# ip alias on the same nic with different subnets on Windows 2008R2

Tags: networking, ip, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Windows 2008R2. 
On a NIC, I have 3 ip aliases :
- two have the same subnet and it works well
- the third is on a different subnet

I can ping the third ip.
I can see the packets who are coming on this ip with Wireshark.

I have a service who list on the 0.0.0.0 address.

When I try to connect to this service, it is like the packet are not going to the service.

I tried with netcat also in listen mode and I had the same problem (If I connect via the loopback ip, netcat receive my datas...)

Is the ip aliases have to be on the same subnet on the same nic ?

Thanks in advance

Best regards

Comment: Connect from same machine or different?  Have you checked the firewall and routing table?  Is the interface actually enabled and "operationally up"?

Comment: I tested from the same and a remote. It seems that there is no firewall problem. The nic is enabled and up because The two first are working and the third can be pinged.

Comment: Can you dump the routing table?  `netstat -r` maybe Windows is trying to reach NIC #3 through the other NICs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will never work. I tried with an additionnal nic and it worked